# Lubuntu 18.04.5 64 stops GPD cooling system for no reason

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, fan, overheating

I have Lubuntu64 LTS on a GPD WIN 1 ver 2 (z8750). Fresh install, no tweaks.
On the login screen, it runs the cooling fan on full speed, but when I log in, it stops the fan immediately. It was OK to this point, but it stops the fan *forever* — on heavy tasks, thermal sensors show "red" >80°C, and it does not run the fan again.

If I log out, the fan runs again.

Looks like a default fan manager is loaded with the user environment, but it works incorrectly. What fan managers Lubuntu can have by default and how to configure/disable them? They seem to override the hardware fan switch on the GPD's rear side. If I remember correctly, older versions of Lubuntu didn't mess with the fan, leaving the hardware switch doing it's job.

According to Synaptic, nothing related to "fan", "speed", "fan control" etc. is currently installed.

BTW Lubuntu+GPD1.2=awesomeness (except this problem).

Update: I've installed LTS 20 (with LXQT) and it works the same way. On the login screen, the hardware switch controls the fan as it should. When I log in, power manager overrides the switch and stops the fan. Is there a way to uninstall the software fan control in Lubuntu? Hardware switch is OK for me, and it's way better than software control working the wrong way.

Comment: LXDE shipped with Lubuntu 18.04 is a pretty dead project, it relies on GTK2 which is not long for this world (MATE, XFCE already ported to GTK3, GTK2 is dead when GIMP completes it's port). Pcman who wrote ``pcmanfm` (handles the GUI & doubles as file manager) ported it to GTK3 but didn't like how heavy it was in comparison to past, so it was re-ported to Qt5 which is lighter; it's now `pcmanfm-qt`. Other LXDE devs joined with RazorQt team creating the LXQt project. Lubuntu finally switched to LXQt in 18.10 and most of the focus has been there

Comment: LXDE is an old software stack, adding extra modern packages to it would destroy the lightness of it, which at the time (Lubuntu 18.04) was against the aims of keeping the system old & light for older hardware (https://lubuntu.me/bionic-released/)  That purpose changed after 18.04's release and prior to 18.10 (https://lubuntu.me/taking-a-new-direction/) as from the point on Lubuntu would be using a modern base and could use more modern features.  Are you asking a question though? as I don't actually see one, it's more a statement with *except this problem* tacked at the end.

Comment: This is such a unique piece of hardware, it's hard to know where to begin.  When running `sensors-detect`, does it detect anything?  Read the output of each section, it may find hardware that it cannot identify.

Comment: I'd rather PREVENT it from detecting the fan. It seem to identify it perfectly, but due to unknown bugs it stops it instead of controlling it. I can tell it from seeing the fan worked perfectly BEFORE the power manager kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I've solved the puzzle.

It happens when I use the external display without the in-built one.

The cooler is connected directly to the display backlight! :-D

The display manager stops the cooling fan, not the power manager. "This is such a unique piece of hardware" is the best comment here!